# Combine values to define a primary key?

Tags: database-design

I have a series of rows with the following information that I want to store in a relational database. I'm thinking about combining the min/max age with the gender to define a primary key but I'm really not sure about it. What do you think would be the best way to solve this?.

```
Min age = 9
Max age = 13
Gender = 'M' 
Nutrient A = 500
Nutrient B = 500
...
Nutrient Z = 600

Min age = 9
Max age = 13
Gender = 'F' 
Nutrient A = 500
Nutrient B = 500
...
Nutrient Z = 600
```

Comment: But if you would want to reference this table later you will have a 3 fielded referenced key in another table. you can identify a surrogate primary key with identity or auto incremented field and define a unique index on these 3 fields

Answer (score 2):

You can just use both fields as your primary key--

```
Age Int NOT NULL,
Gender char NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (Age, Gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new id column. 
Set type to integer. 
Check auto-increment. 
Set column as primary key. 
Let the database handle it.

*Do not rely on a combination of concatenated values to provide a unique identifier.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments, use an auto increment integer for the primary key.  I would only use a natural key for things like an SSN.

Comment: SSN is not a "natural key" since you *will* (in the real world) find duplicates in the wild and because people do change them from time to time (nearly always because of data entry errors, but still: it won't be obvious which record is "wrong"...). PKs should never change.

Comment: @Craig, The fact that SSNs may be erroneously issued to more than one person doesn't automatically mean SSN can't be a natural key. Whether it's sensible to make SSN a key or not depends on the desirability or otherwise of enforcing its uniqueness in the database. In a payroll system for example it probably isn't a good idea to allow duplcates of SSN or any other identifiers used by relevant authorities to identify your employees! It is also no absolute rule that a key mustn't change. Stability is usually desirable but frequently it is useful and even essential to be able to update keys.

Comment: @sqlvogel: We'll have to disagree, then. As it happens, I maintain a commercial payroll system and I can tell you that a new employee will not be happy if they can't be paid due to bad data on an old employee -- perhaps an employee which the person entering the new data doesn't have permission to change! **The pain should go to the person who actually caused the problem, not the person who found it.**

Comment: @Craig, I don't suppose anyone would want to enforce uniqueness across ex-employees. I agree that would probably be unwise (although I expect you would still want to be warned about a duplicate SSN arising). In any case, my point was that you can never definitively say SSN is *not* a natural key because that's something that depends on requirements.

Comment: @sqlvogel: Yes, we give a stern warning about detected duplicates, but we have a general rule of thumb to never impose arbitrary roadblocks to an employee getting their check.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SergeyBenner’s comment. The natural key (what uniquely identifies the data “in real life”) would seem to be {MinAge, MaxAge, Gender}, though this could perhaps be simplified to {Age, Gender}, where you have one row for every possible age/gender (as opposed to one row per age range). However, this would be awkward (at best) to work with if this table has to be the parent of a foreign key relationship, so including a surrogate key (ye olde integer identity column) would provide efficiency. (I’d make the surrogage key the primary key, but I’d also make a clustered unique index on {Age, Gender}.)

Idle curiosity, will you always have 26 columns (A through Z) of data actually populated for every row? If if the number of nutrients varies from group to group, you may want to perform further normalization.

Comment: Yes, the number of nutrients for each group is constant.